# PHP - How to get parameters from shell_exec output

Tags: php, ssl, shell-exec

I need to get SSL certificate details (like expiry date, Issuer) of a domain. So for that I ran the following commands from PHP file.

**ssl.php**

```
$cdates= shell_exec('openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates');
$issuer= shell_exec('openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -issuer');
echo "$cdates";
echo "$issuer";
```

Getting the following **output:**

```
notBefore=Dec 10 11:54:23 2014 GMT notAfter=Mar 10 00:00:00 2015 GMT

issuer= /C=US/O=Google Inc/CN=Google Internet Authority G2
```

Now my question is how can I get the parameters from the variables?

For example I need to get **CN** value (Google Internet Authority G2)  from `$issuer` variable.

So Is there any command/function exists for that or I need to use regular expressions to extract **CN** from the string?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: *I need to use regular expressions...* Yes, you need eg. preg_match

Comment: @donald123 Thanks for your confirmation.. OK I'll try :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this would be a cleaner approach (using [phpseclib](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/intro.html)):

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');

$x509 = new File_X509();
$cert = $x509->loadX509(shell_exec('openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 2>/dev/null'));

print_r($x509->getIssuerDNProp('CN'));
?>
```

Comment: Well, I'm not suppose to use any external libraries. anyway thanks for your answer. :)